# How to create a jQuery plugin that accepts options and action parameters like jQuery UI dialog does

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to write my own dialog plugin and I want it to mirror how the jQuery UI dialog accepts it's parameters.

I.e. The jQuery UI dialog takes options in it's constructor and can be called to open the dialog afterwards without keeping a reference to the dialog element in a variable.

I've read the source for it on GitHub but can't understand how they're accomplishing it.

jQuery way

```
<a onclick="$('#dialog').dialog('open');">test</a>

$( function() {
    // No reference kept
    $('#dialog').dialog({left: 100, top: 10});
});
```

My plugin

```
(function ($) {

    $.fn.modal = function (options) {

        var defaults = { top: 100, overlay: 0.5, closeButton: '.closeDialog' };
        options = $.extend(defaults, options);

        if(options == "open"){
            // open
        }
        if(options == "close"){
            // close
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Why don't you simply copy the code from GitHub and modify it to your liking? Or are you trying to understand it?

Comment: You need to check if `options` is string or not: `var isMethodCall = typeof options === "string";`   https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/0b7246b6eeadfa9e2696e22f3230f6452f8129dc/ui/widget.js#L209

Comment: @RacilHilan I would like to understand and learn how they do it and what, if any, are best practices for doing so. The plugin tutorials on jQuerys site shows passing in actions and options but not how to tell the difference between them once they're passed

Comment: @A.Wolff Is this how jQuery does it? Just curious as to how they accomplish it but that works for me to solve the issue as well. Does this work for checking `return typeof value === 'string' || value instanceof String;`?

Comment: The difference is quite simple. Actions are strings while options are properties of an object. And yes, that's how jQuery does it (as described by A.Wolf)

Comment: @user3953989 I updated comment above

Comment: @A.Wolff Perfect! That should be exactly what I was looking for. I looked the the dialog source not the widget which I guess is generic for all their stuff. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between Actions and Options is quite simple.

Actions are strings:

```
$('#dialog').dialog('open');
```

While options are properties of an object:

```
$('#dialog').dialog({left: 100, top: 10});
```

So a simple check of the type of the provided parameter will do the trick. This is how jQuery does it:

```
var isMethodCall = typeof options === "string";
```